# Why does a child model failing validation on destroy blow up accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We have an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with a `dependent: destroy` that works fine with the `_destroy` param arg.

We added a validation on the child, and that works as expected.

But when we combine the two the save on the parent throws an unhandled error instead of returning false.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :can_do?

  def can_do?
    unless yeah_sure
      errors.add(:base, I18n.t("the.translation"))
      false
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

The `bar_spec` tests `yeah_sure` in both cases, with errors being empty or present (and the correct message is in there).

When I stepped through the rails portion there are 3 levels of catch, rollback/cleanup, and release in active_support and transaction.

I also tried to rescue in the controller, both method level and a begin block, and neither of those trapped the error, which is strange.

Any idea why `foo.save` is throwing an error instead of returning false?

Rails 4.2.10

Comment: Your `Bar` entity is the child of `Foo`, not parent. Please add the log trace for easier understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `inverse_of` to run the validation on nested attributes.

Also, you can reject the attributes using `reject_if block`
please refer the following [link](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1346-popular-mistakes-when-using-nested-forms).

Comment: We have tried `inverse_of` and it didn't resolve.  We don't want to ignore hashes, we want to delete child records so `reject_if` won't help.